# Writing custom class - requiring a specific engine

Tags: pdftex, luatex, document-classes

I am writing a class which specifies the correct layout for my institution (actually I am modifying an old version). The class includes two custom fonts (Verdana and Georgia) and a logo which should appear in the header.

I have the fonts in afm and pfb format and know how to install them, but I feel that using LuaLaTeX is so much easier and I would like to use that. Now my question is, is there a way to make sure that this class is always typeset using LuaLaTeX? If I add the lines which includes the fonts, it no longer works to compile it with pdftex.

Comment: `\ifx\directlua\@undefined\ClassError{myclass}{Go away}{}\stop\fi`

Comment: There is also the `iflualatex` package.

Comment: If you are planning for other people to use this, I strongly suggest trying very hard to avoid requiring a particular engine, especially LuaTeX and particularly if this is for e.g. typesetting dissertations or something. I advise students to stick to pdfTeX for this kind of purpose because it is more stable and reliable. If you do insist on LuaTeX, your documentation should make clear that people should not update their TeX installations close to a deadline. For GNU/Linux users using their distro's packages, this will be a headache.

Comment: Note, however, that LuaTeX 1.0 was released in summer 2016. I suspect (but certainly don't know) that TeX Live 2017 will include it as part of the release.  In fact, TL2016 has version 0.95, so it is fairly easy to check whether there will be any show-stopping changes you need to prepare for.  That said, you cannot always be sure that people will be using the TL2016(+) since many OSes distribute their own version of the binaries and invariably lag behind the current release candidates ... and there is, e.g., a very big difference between version 0.70 and 0.95.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I am actually just using the fontspec package, so I guess it could work with XeTeX as well. Also, the class will be used mainly for writing (official) letters with no math or complicated symbols. The reason I insist on using fontspec is that the official document fonts are Verdana and Georgia and those does not seem to be part of the regular LaTeX fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the answer was posted in one of the comments:

```
\ifx\directlua\@undefined\ClassError{myclass}{Go away}{}\stop\fi
```